# Removing duplicate copies (html extension vs non-html)

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

Is there any way to have the first URL redirect to the second URL?

http://www.example.com/podcast/episode.html
http://www.example.com/podcast/episode

Is there any way to force the .html extension to redirect to the non-html version of the URL, so as not to show up as duplicate copies of the same page.

My htaccess code at the moment is:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #removing trailing slash

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

    #non www to www

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    #shtml

    AddType text/html .html
    AddHandler server-parsed .html

    #html

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

    #index redirect

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/ 
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Is the .htaccess file in your document root or in your podcast directory? This is a really, really important detail.

Comment: @JonLin The .htaccess is in the document root.

Comment: No idea what's wrong, I paste your rules and Tim Stoop's rules into a test apache server and they work fine.

Comment: @JonLin Did you add Tim's rule to the top of the htaccess or... where?

Comment: @JonLin Just to let you know, finally found an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321203/how-to-redirect-html-extension-using-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if I understand the question, but if you want anything ending in .html to redirect to the same URL without the .html, this should do the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I tried that and it redirected [http://www.pavlinaplus.com/podcast/growth.html] to [http://www.pavlinaplus.com/growth]

Comment: I forgot the ^ in front of it, try again please!

Comment: Still not working unfortunately. In fact, something happened so that now pavlinaplus.com/podcast/growth redirects to pavlinaplus.com/growth. (pavlinaplus.com/podcast/growth.html still works though)

Comment: Finally found an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321203/how-to-redirect-html-extension-using-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do the redirection from html to non-html only.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ (/[^\ ]+)\.html\  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
```